# Can't understand this IEnumerable<T>.ToArray() example

Tags: c#, linq

In following lines i do understand LINQ part but then i get totally numb when i try to understand last line.

```
var roles=from r in db.Role
               from u in db.User
               where r.RoleID==u.RoleID
               && u.UserName==username
               select new
                 {
                    RoleNames=r.RoleName
                 };
               return new string[] {roles.ToArray()[0].RoleNames};
```

Variable `roles` is of type IEnumerable (right?) and it contains anonymous collection of `RoleNames` objects?
Last line, to complicated assignment to string[]`{roles.ToArray()[0].RoleNames}`.
,`roles` converted to array (OK) and then phantom index [0] (Why?) and then at the end `RoleNames` anonymous type that is contained by `roles` but how does this all become an array of strings.
Thx in advanced for even a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to say from just this snippet of code, but it feels like this code is not doing what the author intended.

Why does user have a RoleID column? If users can only have one role, then that's OK. But this code seems to imply users can have multiple roles. Does the user table contain multiple entries for each user, one with each of their assigned roles?  Users/Roles is typically a many to many relation.

The original author is taking the result of that query and just grabbing the first result of it (in that case, a call to `roles.First()` is probably more appropriate), and then taking the one role there and returning it in an array. If this array will only have one element, then that is OK but boy that doesn't *feel* right. If the author was going after multiple roles, they are only going to get one. Not to mention if no roles at all are found, this code will blow up.

If a user can truly only have one role, then there are simpler (and easier to read) ways of getting that role. Maybe something like:

```
var roles=from r in db.Role
           from u in db.User
           where r.RoleID==u.RoleID
           && u.UserName==username
           select r.RoleName;

 // at this point roles will probably have zero or one entry, so you can do
 return roles.FirstOrDefault(); // return the one role found as a string
     // or null if none were

 // or if you really do want the array
 return roles.ToArray(); // will return a string array,
     // possibly having 1 or 0 elements
```

Comment: Yeah man, you cleared it all!  In my solution 'user' has only one 'role' but the author of this code is definitely AnySolution-guy :)  And you gave me solution for method 'GetRolesForUser' in Custom Role Provider that i'm using for ASP.NET MVC app. Thx allot for clearing this. Going back to laboratory :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 return new string[] {roles.ToArray()[0].RoleNames};
```

`ToArray()` returns an array of an anonymous type with a `RoleNames` property. The indexer `[0]` then returns the first element of this array and the property accessor `.RoleNames` finally returns its `RoleNames` property. This is just a single string, but the `new string[] {..}` makes it a string array with a single element.

Answer (score 2):

The last line realises the query into an array, then it takes just the first item of the array, and creates a new string array from the `RoleNames` property of that item.

A better solution would be to just get the value of the `RoleName` property instead of creating a new object with a property containing it:

```
var roles =
  from r in db.Role
  from u in db.User
  where r.RoleID == u.RoleID && u.UserName == username
  select r.RoleName;
```

As `roles` is an `IEnumerable<string>`, you can use the `Take` method to limit the result to the first string, which you then can turn into an array;

```
return roles.Take(1).ToArray();
```

As you limit the result before realising it using the `ToArray` method, it will only need to read the first item, instead of reading all of the items and then throw away everything but the first one.

Why the single string should be returned as an array is not obvious. If that is a mistake, and it should actaully return all the role names, just remove the `Take(1)` from the code.

Comment: Thx, this is quite interesting. I can really learn a lot on this forum :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that it works as intended.

It only returns the role name from the first match.

Instead, the code should be something like

```
var roles=(from r in db.Role
           from u in db.User
           where r.RoleID==u.RoleID
           && u.UserName==username
           select r.RoleName).ToArray();
return roles;
```

which, it turns out, is pretty well what's described in the Accepted Answer!

If the user can have only one role, and it can be guaranteed that they have a valid role ID, and that the calling code expects an array, then this code will work as expected, but it's not exactly the most straightforward way of doing it.